# DOM assign an id to child Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a grid with div, class and id. I want to randomly create a yellow square and I want to assign an id= 'yellowSquare' how do I do it?

```js
var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}

var playerOne = [];

while (playerOne.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random());


  if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerOne.push(randomIndex);

    var drawPone = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    drawPone.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

```css
#grid-box {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 0;
position: relative;
}

#grid-box>div.square {
font-size: 1rem;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-box"></div>
```

I am new to Javascript / jQuery. Any help will be much appreciated ! Thank you

Comment: It seems like your code already does the things your asking for help to do :) Edit: ...except the ID yes... are you looking for ways to create a child element inside a square, or simply give the yellow square a new ID now?

Comment: `drawPone.id = "yellowSquare"` ?

Comment: What do you want to change in the "program"? It looks like your code already does the things you asked for.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants **change** the `id` already assigned? Then @freedomn-m is correct. Otherwise need clarification.

Comment: The square you make yellow already has an id `'square' + i` - if you *change* that id to `yellowSquare` then it will no longer have the original id so won't be able to be referenced that way.  I suggest you *keep* the original indexed id and use a `class` instead:  `$(drawPone).addClass("yellowSquare")` (as tagged jquery) - you can then reference this with `$(".yellowSquare")` without destroying the indexed id.

Comment: In my opinion dynamic id's are a bad practice too. Id's are identifiers and should be used to identify elements (has to be unique too for that reason too). Better would be to use class or a data attribute for this issue. You could compare it by changing the id of a database record or even the id document of a person.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I think Im gonna go for this $(drawPone).addClass("yellowSquare")!

Comment: If I want to move the yellow square along axis x & y by mouse click do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: This reminds me of the "how do I turn off the sun"-question, when it in reality is "how can i make it a bit cooler" that the question is really about ;). I've asked my fair share of those, and still do from time to time :)

Comment: @Liam_Miller, I would personally create a custom data value for all elements, representing the number on x and y axis. see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp. Then I would remember the initial placement in two variables named x and y in javascript. Upon input, I'd first remove "yellowSquare" from all elements (select all grid elements for that) have the x or y respectively add or subtract accordingly to the variables, and use the specific data attribute selector to identify the correct new square, and then assign class yellowsquare on that one. Lots of new terms to google here.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to your question. You can either change the id of the yellow square which is already created from your code, or create a child element within the square, which looks the same as your current solution. Creating a new child element will let you keep the numeric id pattern for the grid:

Changing the ID :

```
var element = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex)
element.id = "yellowSquare";
```

Adding new element inside:

```
var node = document.createElement("DIV");
node.id = "yellowSquare";
node.style = "background-color:yellow;height:100%;width:100%;";
var element = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex)
element.appendChild(node);
```

I set the styling of the div child to 100% width and height, as it has no content, and would get 0 values if nothing was specified. This should make it fill the parent container.

There are also multiple other ways to achieve the same result, for instance with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTMLElement method `setAttribute` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute));

```
...

var drawPone = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
drawPone.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
drawPone.setAttribute('id', 'yellowSquare');

...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you requested in your comment how to move the square i made an example how you can move it left and right using jQuery `next()` and `prev()` functions. However because your html elements are 1 dimensional it's not easy to move them up/down and check the sides for collisions. Better would be to create your html table like with rows and columns and this way create a 2 dimensional play field.

Also added a yellowSquery class for selection with `$drawPone.addClass('yellowSquare');`.

Also since you like to use jQuery I changed your existing code to jQuery function. Might help you learn the framework.

```js
var $grid = $("#grid-box");
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var $square = $("<div>");
  $square.addClass('square');
  
  $square.attr('id','square' + i);
  $grid.append($square);
}


var playerOne = [];

while (playerOne.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(99 * Math.random());

  if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerOne.push(randomIndex);

    var $drawPone = $('#square' + randomIndex);
    $drawPone.addClass('yellowSquare');
  }
}

$('#button_right').on('click', function(){
  $yellowSquare = $('.yellowSquare')
  $yellowSquareNext = $yellowSquare.next();
  $yellowSquare.removeClass('yellowSquare');
  $yellowSquareNext.addClass('yellowSquare');
});

$('#button_left').on('click', function(){
  $yellowSquare = $('.yellowSquare')
  $yellowSquarePrev = $yellowSquare.prev();
  $yellowSquare.removeClass('yellowSquare');
  $yellowSquarePrev.addClass('yellowSquare');
});
```

```css
#grid-box {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 0;
position: relative;
}

#grid-box>div.square {
font-size: 1rem;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.yellowSquare {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-box"></div>

<button id="button_left">left</button>
<button id="button_right">right</button><br>
```